# Stack Overflow logins

Tags: discussion, login

Why I need to create different accounts to Stack Overflow sites? Why Stack Overflow sites does not use one account only? I have different account to Stack Overflow and ask ubuntu.

If account already exist to one site, anybody can create account with the same login to another site and I see all accounts to user page.

Comment: Isn't your account associated with your email? So in this case no-one should be able creating another account with the email you currently use. Or perhaps simply sign in with your social account (again tied to your email) ... Don't see the issue, unless I miss something.

Comment: This is [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) question I believe, and you will have to register.

Answer (score 4):

You do not have to create "different" accounts.  When you go to a site that you are not registered with, you can attach your existing account to that site.  In fact, when you do, you get 100 points automatically added to your account on the new site because you are already a "trusted member".

When you are on a new SE site, click "Sign Up".  One of the options is to use your Stack Exchange account to sign up.  Just plug in your account info and you can use that same account on the new site too.

Comment: Even with linked accounts, having to create a hundred accounts is pretty annoying.

Comment: @CodesInChaos It's just clicking two-ish buttons when you want to link your account, compared to the overhead that it would be for the Stack Exchange to automatically create your account on 100 sites when most members only use a couple. Do you really want to link your account to every Stack Exchange website? Do you plan on asking and answering questions on 100 different sites? Then why should the resources be spent to provide that to you if you'll never use it? It's just a question of unnecessary overhead and how to avoid it.